# occurring issues with embed creating system

Tags: python, discord.py

There are a few problems with this system. Now, there were other problems, but i've managed to solve them just not these problems. Im storing the created embeds in a json file for easy access.

1. once i click and submit the footer part of the embed i can't re-edit the information in it, this problem is because of the timestamp code since i tried to re-edit without it.

```
class footer(ui.Modal, title="Edit Footer"):
        ftext = ui.TextInput(label="Edit footer text", placeholder="Encourage life", style=discord.TextStyle.long, required=False)
        fticon = ui.TextInput(label="Edit footer image", placeholder="https://www.chickenCLT.png", style=discord.TextStyle.long, required=False)
        time = ui.TextInput(label="Timestamp", placeholder="Yes/No", style=discord.TextStyle.short, min_length=2, max_length=6, required=False)

        def __init__(self, original_embed: discord.Embed):
            super().__init__()
            if original_embed.footer:
                self.ftext.default = original_embed.footer.text
                self.fticon.default = original_embed.footer.icon_url
                self.time.default = original_embed.timestamp

        async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            embed = interaction.message.embeds[0]
            if self.ftext:
                embed.set_footer(text=self.ftext.value, icon_url=self.fticon.value)

            if self.time.value.lower() == "yes":
                embed.timestamp = datetime.now()
            else:
                embed.timestamp = None

            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
```

```
    @discord.ui.button(label="Edit Footer", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="edit_footer")
    async def edit_footer(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(footer(original_embed=interaction.message.embeds[0]))
```

error

```
2023-11-01 20:00:18 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <MainView timeout=180.0 children=4> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.secondary: 2> url=None disabled=False label='Edit Footer' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\trace\Desktop\MU LFG\lfg bot\main.py", line 181, in edit_footer
    await interaction.response.send_modal(footer(original_embed=interaction.message.embeds[0]))
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 972, in send_modal
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 151, in request
    to_send = utils._to_json(payload)
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 650, in _to_json
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in 
encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in 
iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in 
default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

so instead of just storing the embed name should i also store the information?

2. cant edit embed color, ive tried changing the code a few times but i still havent gotten it yet.

```
class general(ui.Modal,title="edit general info"):
    embed_title = ui.TextInput(label="edit title",placeholder="life",style=discord.TextStyle.long,required=False)
    embed_description = ui.TextInput(label="edit description",placeholder="life",style=discord.TextStyle.long,required=False)
    hex_color = ui.TextInput(label="edit hex color code",placeholder="#000fff",style=discord.TextStyle.short,required=False)


    def __init__(self, original_embed: discord.Embed):
        super().__init__()
        if original_embed.footer:
            self.embed_title.default = original_embed.title
            self.embed_description.default = original_embed.description
            self.hex_color.default = original_embed.color.value



    async def on_submit(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        embed = interaction.message.embeds[0]
        if self.hex_color:

            your_hex = self.hex_color
            embed.color = discord.Color.from_str(your_hex)
        else:
            embed.color = None
```

error

```
2023-11-01 20:17:15 ERROR    discord.ui.modal Ignoring exception in modal <general timeout=None children=3>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\modal.py", line 188, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\trace\Desktop\MU LFG\lfg bot\main.py", line 159, in on_submit
    embed.color = discord.Color.from_str(your_hex)
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\colour.py", line 199, in from_str
    if value[0] == '#':
TypeError: 'TextInput' object is not subscriptable
```

is editing a embed color not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to pass a string to text imput default value:

```py
self.time.default = "No"
```

2. You need to pass the imput text value, not the object itself:

```py
embed.color = discord.Color.from_str(your_hex.value)
```